# Protecting jsTree Styles from Other jsTree Instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, jstree

Is it possible to prefix the class names generated by the [jsTree jQuery plugin/library](https://www.jstree.com/)? If not is there a known path forward to have a single page share two jsTree elements that are styled differently?

The Problem:

I have a plugin for (a PHP based) content management system.  This plugin uses the jsTree jQuery plugin to create several tree views that are visible on all pages.

The CMS UI *also* uses jsTree on a few of its pages, and our styles are conflicting with one another.

The DOM generation is complex enough that simply prefixing all the default styles with an ID **does not work**.

```
/* my 2008 era CSS tricks are no help, this does not work */

#an-id-on-the-div-that-contains-mytrees .jstree-node,
#an-id-on-the-div-that-contains-mytrees .jstree-children,
#an-id-on-the-div-that-contains-mytrees .jstree-container-ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
}
```

The default CSS file is over 1,000 lines, and the prospect of carefully and surgically figuring out which style class is used where and supplying a more specific CSS rule for every existing rule is more than a little daunting.

I'm asking if there's a known path forward for quickly/easily using two jsTrees with different styles on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsTree has support for using themes with its setup configuration.

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
  "core" : {
    "themes": { "name": "mycustomtheme", "dots": true, "icons": true }
  }
});
```

You can use the default CSS [here](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/dist/themes/default/style.css) as a template to modify the default class `.jstree-default` with your theme class `.jstree-mycustomtheme`. You can have multiple CSS stylesheets and apply them with the theme configuration. Although it's not the quickest approach, this is the extent of what jsTree supports at the moment.